Speeding up Cholesky Decomposition in Gaussian Process Regression
I am currently working on a project that is pulling posterior samples from a Gaussian Process according to the following formula:
$Y(x) = \mu(x) + (\Sigma)^{1/2}\mathcal{Z}$
where $\mu(x)$ is a mean function, $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix and $\mathcal{Z}$ is a distribution of normal samples. The square root of the covariance matrix is done using a Cholesky decomposition because the covariance matrix is symmetric positive definite. The problem is that the Cholesky decomposition is $O(n^3)$ complexity. With large datasets, this becomes prohibitively expensive.
I am looking for ideas on how to speed up the Cholesky decomposition and was wondering if anyone was aware of previous work that has looked into this. So far, I have just looked at using a Nystrom approximation. However, to my understanding, this is just a low rank approximation to the covariance matrix and would not provide me with any measurable increase in efficiency when computing the Cholesky decomposition. I am open to any ideas or suggestions of work I should look into.

What is the complete data model? What priors? Does $\Sigma$ have any structure?

@ZackFisher $\Sigma$ is a symmetric positive definite square matrix where each element is determined by a covariance kernel (like the Matern kernel for example). The data comes from queries to some sort of function that we are looking to approximate. The GP priors are a distribution of functions determined by the mean function and covariance function. Each function has some uncertainty except where we observe points to the true function.

I'd suggest that the question be edited so that such (and more) details are included. Otherwise the question seems too broad to me. I think properties of your special kernel are needed, if substantial simplification is wanted.

I see. Thanks for your suggestion @ZackFisher. I will get around to editing the question
